# CouchDB view structure

Tags: couchdb

Lets say i have collection of users. They have "subjects" and each subject has priority -- which determines what priority has user in this subject. I had a few situations like this, but for now let it be users, subjects and priorities.

I want to display users who have selected subject and sort them by priority of this subject. Users and subjetcs are in "many to many" realtions and this is the sample user structure:

```
{ name:"Nic", 
  subjects: [
   { name:"math", priority:10}, 
   { name:"english", priority: 11} ...]}
```

How I should organize the view structure?

First variant is to create view `by-subject`, reduce the users by subject key and get the list of "math" users like `_view/by-subjects?key="math"&reduce=true`. But this case I have to sort by priority in client application...

Second is to create separate view for each subject and emit `priority` as a key. So i could take the data from `_view/math?descending=true` and it would be sorted. But as I understood each time when new user  inserted in DB all the 42 views will be updated (in case I have 42 subjects). In first case I have only one view to be updated.

So, the question is: which variant is more preferable for CouchDB, or more idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you emit

`[":subject",":user",":priority"]`

as key and request `?key="math"` you will get an alphabetical sorted list of user and their priorities.

If you emit

`[":subject",":priority",":user"]`

You get the same list sorted by `priority`. The you can also ask for the top-ten by addin `?limit=10`

Comment: actually, i'm stuck a bit again.. If i `emit` key like `["math", 8]` i had to request exactly the whole key, like `?key=["math",8]`. Otherwise i get no rows in answer

Comment: you shouldn't - how many times i needed a friendly help to step back and see the easy solution for something that i had several complicated answers for :-)

Comment: I would recommend to use strings in the keys and request with `startkey` and `endkey`. If you use the first \u0000 and the last \u9999 unicode char as 'placeholder' it should be possible to request w/o the exact key.

Comment: yes, thanks. Just read about startkey few min ago, looks like what I need here